# How often do I need to invoke Parse.subscribeInBackground() in order to subscribe to Parse pushes?

Tags: android, parse-platform

We're using Parse.com services to deliver push notifications to our Android app. These notifications are coming in some specific channel and we can assume that the channel remains the same from the app installation till its removal.
Now, there is a method [Parse.subscribeInBackground(String, SaveCallback)](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePush.html#subscribeInBackground(java.lang.String,%20com.parse.SaveCallback)):

> public static void subscribeInBackground(String channel,
>                            SaveCallback callback)
>   Adds 'channel' to the 'channels' list in the current ParseInstallation and saves it in a background thread.
>   Parameters:
>   channel - The channel to subscribe to.
>   callback - The SaveCallback that is called after the Installation is saved.

The documentation is a little unclear because I don't understand how often do I need to invoke this method in our app? Do I need to

- invoke it just once, make sure it was successful via the provided callback and don't invoke it again
- or do I need to invoke it every time the app starts (because the process of subscription may require that some services are started, some broadcast receivers are registered, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call it each time the app starts...

In this tutorial (https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) they call `ParsePush.subscribeInBackground` from the app's `onCreate` method.